# Need to display a website on a fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I am trying to display an external website in a fragment on a webview. Although when i open the fragment, i get a blank screen. Kindly help me with the same.

public class one extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

```
public one() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private WebView mWebview ;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    FrameLayout framelayout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    mWebview = (WebView) framelayout.findViewById(R.id.web);
    WebSettings setting =mWebview.getSettings();
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    //webView.loadUrl("http://www.cleankutz.appointy.com");
    mWebview.loadUrl("https://www.cleankutz.appointy.com");

    return framelayout;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need the following in the manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Here are some things you can try:

1. **Make sure that internet is enabled in your device when testing**
2. Enable java script:

   ```
      WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ```

Also, I find this code quite useless:

```
  mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

That just overrides any link clicks. And if you want to do that, you should just not set the web view client. Also, just a bonus, if you want your webview to go back on back press, do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Please accept my answer by pressing the checkmark if this helped. If you have more questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: I have already included the permission in the manifest. And if i dont add the .setWebViewClient(), the url opens up in a web browser. Although, i want to display it within the fragment.